# How to fill between two lines in a graphic?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, graphics

I have three arrays. xValues, yMinValues and yMaxValues. I want to show a graphic and this graphic must draw two lines by my yminValues and yMaxValues array.Then fill with a color between this lines. I draw all lines but I get a graphic like in that photo and I show.

[image]

My Code is:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    let xValues: [CGFloat] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
    let yMaxValues: [CGFloat] = [4, 6, 9, 10, 10, 11, 10, 11]
    let yMinValues: [CGFloat] = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        // Arka planı beyaz yapın
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)
        
        // Grafik boyutlarını alın
        let graphWidth = rect.width
        let graphHeight = rect.height
        
        // Min ve max değerleri belirleyin
        let minValue = min(yMinValues.min() ?? 0.0, yMinValues.max() ?? 0.0)
        let maxValue = max(yMaxValues.min() ?? 0.0, yMaxValues.max() ?? 0.0)
        
        // Y değerlerini ölçeklendirin
        let yScaleFactor = graphHeight / (maxValue - minValue)
        
        // X değerlerini ölçeklendirin
        let xScaleFactor = graphWidth / CGFloat(xValues.count - 1)
        
        // Grafik alanını doldurun
        let yFillValuesPath = UIBezierPath()

        // YFillValues için line çizin
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * xScaleFactor
            let yFill = graphHeight - (yMinValues[i] - minValue) * yScaleFactor // Burada yMinValues kullanılmalı
            if i == 0 {
                yFillValuesPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: yFill))
            } else {
                yFillValuesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: yFill))
            }

            // Noktalara yFillValues değerlerini yaz
            let pointLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x - 15, y: yFill - 30, width: 30, height: 30))
            pointLabel.text = "\(yMinValues[i])"
            pointLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            pointLabel.textAlignment = .center
            pointLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
            addSubview(pointLabel)
        }
        
        // Grafik alanını doldurun
        let fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
        fillColor.setFill()
        
        yFillValuesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: yMaxValues.last ?? 0, y: graphHeight - (yMaxValues.last ?? 0 - minValue) * yScaleFactor)) // yMinValues kullanılmalı
        yFillValuesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: yMinValues.first ?? 0, y: graphHeight - (yMinValues.first ?? 0 - maxValue) * yScaleFactor)) // yMinValues kullanılmalı
    
        
        yFillValuesPath.fill()

        yFillValuesPath.close()
        
        // YValues için line çizin
        let yValuesPath = UIBezierPath()
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * xScaleFactor
            let y = graphHeight - (yMaxValues[i] - minValue) * yScaleFactor
            if i == 0 {
                yValuesPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            } else {
                yValuesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            }
            
            // Noktalara yValues değerlerini yaz
            let pointLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x - 15, y: y - 30, width: 30, height: 30))
            pointLabel.text = "\(yMaxValues[i])"
            pointLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            pointLabel.textAlignment = .center
            pointLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
            addSubview(pointLabel)
        }
        
        // Çizgileri çizin
        let lineColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        context.setStrokeColor(lineColor)
        yValuesPath.stroke()
        yFillValuesPath.stroke()
        
        // X ekseni çizin
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: graphHeight))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: graphWidth, y: graphHeight))
        context.strokePath()
        
        // Y ekseni çizin
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: graphHeight))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        context.strokePath()
        
        // X değerlerini gösterin
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * xScaleFactor
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x - 15, y: graphHeight + 5, width: 30, height: 20))
            label.text = "\(xValues[i])"
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            addSubview(label)
        }
        
        // Y değerlerini gösterin
        for i in 0..<yMaxValues.count {
            let y = graphHeight - (yMaxValues[i] - minValue) * yScaleFactor
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -35, y: y - 10, width: 30, height: 20))
            label.text = "\(yMaxValues[i])"
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            label.textAlignment = .right
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            addSubview(label)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show a graphic filled with a color between yMinValues array and yMaxValues.

[image]

I don't want to fill outer fields and marked these fields with text in this photo.

Comment: Just draw small rectangle corresponding to (X[n],Ymin[n])/(X[n],Ymax[n])/(X[n+1],Ymax[n+1])/(X[n+1],Ymin[n+1]). Then you can stroke the X,Ymin and X,Ymax lines.

Comment: I did as you said. But I have a lot of spaces fields because of rectangles' around.

Comment: @esradidem - your question is not entirely clear. You show an image of what you **don't want** ... add an image showing what you **do want**.

Comment: I get, you are right. I added what I want the last photo at the end of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the area between the lines, we need to create a single path.

So, we start with a "max values line" - actually, a set of points:

[image]

then we have a "min values line" - also, a set of points:

[image]

to fill the space, we need to turn those into a single path, in this order:

[image]

then we can fill and stroke it:

[image]

Here is your `CustomView` class, with a few modifications...

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    let xValues: [CGFloat] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
    let yMaxValues: [CGFloat] = [4, 6, 9, 10, 10, 11, 10, 11]
    let yMinValues: [CGFloat] = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        // Arka planı beyaz yapın
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)
        
        // Grafik boyutlarını alın
        let graphWidth = rect.width
        let graphHeight = rect.height
        
        // Min ve max değerleri belirleyin
        let minValue = min(yMinValues.min() ?? 0.0, yMinValues.max() ?? 0.0)
        let maxValue = max(yMaxValues.min() ?? 0.0, yMaxValues.max() ?? 0.0)
        
        // Y değerlerini ölçeklendirin
        let yScaleFactor = graphHeight / (maxValue - minValue)
        
        // X değerlerini ölçeklendirin
        let xScaleFactor = graphWidth / CGFloat(xValues.count - 1)
        
        var yMinPoints: [CGPoint] = []
        var yMaxPoints: [CGPoint] = []

        // build CGPoint arrays for min and max values points
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * xScaleFactor
            let yMin = graphHeight - (yMinValues[i] - minValue) * yScaleFactor
            let yMax = graphHeight - (yMaxValues[i] - minValue) * yScaleFactor
            yMinPoints.append(.init(x: x, y: yMin))
            yMaxPoints.append(.init(x: x, y: yMax))
        }
        
        // Grafik alanını doldurun
        let yFillValuesPath = UIBezierPath()

        // build path, starting at first max point
        yFillValuesPath.move(to: yMaxPoints[0])
        // add lines to the remaing max points
        for i in 1..<yMaxPoints.count {
            yFillValuesPath.addLine(to: yMaxPoints[i])
        }
        // reverse the min points
        let yMinReversed = Array(yMinPoints.reversed())
        // add lines to the reversed min points
        for i in 0..<yMinReversed.count {
            yFillValuesPath.addLine(to: yMinReversed[i])
        }
        
        // close the path
        yFillValuesPath.close()
        
        // fill the path
        let fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
        fillColor.setFill()
        yFillValuesPath.fill()
        
        // stroke the path
        let lineColor = UIColor.black
        lineColor.setStroke()
        yFillValuesPath.stroke()

        // add the point labels
        for i in 0..<yMaxPoints.count {
            // Noktalara yFillValues değerlerini yaz
            var pointLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: yMaxPoints[i].x - 15, y: yMaxPoints[i].y - 30, width: 30, height: 30))
            pointLabel.text = "\(yMaxValues[i])"
            pointLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            pointLabel.textAlignment = .center
            pointLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
            addSubview(pointLabel)

            pointLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: yMinPoints[i].x - 15, y: yMinPoints[i].y - 30, width: 30, height: 30))
            pointLabel.text = "\(yMinValues[i])"
            pointLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            pointLabel.textAlignment = .center
            pointLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
            addSubview(pointLabel)
        }

        // X ekseni çizin
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: graphHeight))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: graphWidth, y: graphHeight))
        context.strokePath()
        
        // Y ekseni çizin
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: graphHeight))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        context.strokePath()
        
        // X değerlerini gösterin
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * xScaleFactor
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x - 15, y: graphHeight + 5, width: 30, height: 20))
            label.text = "\(xValues[i])"
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            addSubview(label)
        }
        
        // Y değerlerini gösterin
        for i in 0..<yMaxValues.count {
            let y = graphHeight - (yMaxValues[i] - minValue) * yScaleFactor
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -35, y: y - 10, width: 30, height: 20))
            label.text = "\(yMaxValues[i])"
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            label.textAlignment = .right
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            addSubview(label)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That works as long as both lines go all the way from minX to MaxX with no gaps and they don't cross. If the two lines cross you might get unexpected fill behavior. If there are gaps then filling won't work. Slicing it into a series of 1-point-thick rectangles (with a little logic to handle the case where the lines cross) would handle those cases as well.

Comment: @DuncanC - valid comments, although... assuming no gaps (the OP's original code did no array bounds checking) and assuming every pair has minY < maxY (again, no checking in OP's code)... I don't *think* the lines could cross? Certainly could use additional data-sanity checks.

Comment: Yeah, the naming of the arrays `yminValues` and `yMaxValues` implies that the max value entry at a given x should be > the min value at that x. If that's correct they should never cross.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you really so much!. You saved me. Solving is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just draw small rectangle corresponding to (X[n],Ymin[n])/(X[n],Ymax[n])/(X[n+1],Ymax[n+1])/(X[n+1],Ymin[n+1]). Then you can stroke the X,Ymin and X,Ymax lines

```
...
    //        yFillValuesPath.fill() <<-- Remove the fill
... 
    // Loop on values
    for i in 1..<xValues.count {
        // Compute path points
        let x0 = CGFloat(i-1) * xScaleFactor
        let x1 = CGFloat(i) * xScaleFactor
        let yMax0 = graphHeight - (yMaxValues[i-1] - minValue) * yScaleFactor
        let yMax1 = graphHeight - (yMaxValues[i] - minValue) * yScaleFactor
        let yMin0 = graphHeight - (yMinValues[i-1] - minValue) * yScaleFactor
        let yMin1 = graphHeight - (yMinValues[i] - minValue) * yScaleFactor
        
        // Fill path
        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: x0, y: yMin0))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x0, y: yMax0))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x1, y: yMax1))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x1, y: yMin1))
        context.closePath()
        context.fillPath() // Fill path without stroke
    }
```